# NPOI: Edit cell

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I am using the following code to edit cells of an excel file but I dont see my changes in the escel file.

```
    using (var fs = new FileStream(reconnFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        HSSFWorkbook template = new HSSFWorkbook(fs, true);
        ISheet sheet = template.GetSheetAt(0);

        int rownumber=3;
        foreach(StringBuilder cardHolderValue in cardHolderValues)
        {
            sheet.GetRow(rownumber).Cells[2].SetCellValue(cardHolderValue.ToString());
            rownumber++;
        }
    }
```

And I can't find any `Save()` function in it to do so. Please let me know how can I save my edits.

Comment: You can use this solution to edit excel col row with NPOI
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57250186/6443916

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Create-Excel-Spreadsheets-Using-NPOI.aspx#s7-conclusion. There is a Write method to save your excel file.

Answer (score 0):

template.Write(new FileStream("c:/path", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite));