# NPOI SetCellValue method doesn't write data to cells

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, npoi

I have some problem with writing data to Excel worksheet cells using `NPOI`. 
**Here is my code:**

```
        FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        hssfworkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        ISheet sheet1 = hssfworkbook.GetSheet("Табель");
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < table.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (table.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString() != "0")
                    sheet1.GetRow(i+5).GetCell(j).SetCellValue(table.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString());
                else
                    sheet1.GetRow(i+5).GetCell(j).SetCellValue("");
            }
        }
        string save_path = Server.MapPath("~/templates/report_new.xls");
        FileStream save_file = new FileStream(save_path, FileMode.Create);
        hssfworkbook.Write(save_file);
        save_file.Close();
```

I know that the process of opening existing worksheet works, because I have a new saved worksheet named "report_new" after this code runs. It correctly opens an existing worksheet because the newly saved file has the same template inside. But it has no data I needed. So SetCellValue method in the loop doesn't work and doesn't write data to cells. I checked that my data source represented by the DataSet named "table" isn't empty, so data exists. But it doesn't write it to cells.
What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of these approaches to write into the cell of excel

```
   var row = sheet.CreateRow(0);
   row.CreateCell(j).SetCellValue(table.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString());

    // or 
    row.Cells[j].SetCellValue(table.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString());


    // Or 


    ISheet sheet1 = hssfworkbook.GetSheet("Табель");
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {  
            HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow)sheet1.GetRow(i+5);

        for (int j = 0; j < table.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
        {
    if (table.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString() != "0")
        row.GetCell(j).SetCellValue(table.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString());
    else
        row.GetCell(j).SetCellValue("");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create function to SetValue(sheet, col, row, value)

here is sample

```
SetCellValue(sheet, cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex, value);

private static void SetCellValue(ISheet worksheet, int rowPosition, int columnPosition, String value)
        {
            IRow dataRow = worksheet.GetRow(rowPosition) ?? worksheet.CreateRow(rowPosition);
            ICell cell = dataRow.GetCell(columnPosition) ?? dataRow.CreateCell(columnPosition);
            cell.SetCellValue(value);
        }
```